# Ignore sibling order in Scene Kit overlaySKScene

Tags: ios, macos, sprite-kit, scenekit, skcropnode

I am using an overlaySKScene in Scene Kit. In that SKScene, I am using a mask node to crop an SKCropNode. The mask node works perfectly when run on Mac OS X, but when I run it on iOS it doesn't work.

I think that's because iOS is ignoring sibling order and the mask node shows up behind the SKCropNode. When I try to set

```
view.ignoreSiblingOrder = NO;
```

in SKScene, it crashes and says:

```
[GameView setIgnoresSiblingOrder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

GameView is a subclass of SCNView, so I understand SCNView doesn't have the property "ignoreSiblingOrder".

How do I solve this? Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is it a bug in Scene Kit when run on iOS?

Comment: Can't you just explicitly set the zPosition?

Comment: Tried that, again it works on OSX perfectly but not on iOS. @EpicByte